# Input text value based on select option value loaded dynamically from sql db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that has a select field that loads the options dynamically from a db result query. Here is what the code looks like. See the description text input afterwards? I need the code to return the description of the item selected under productID. How do I go about this? Thanks very much for all replies.

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <label>SKU</label>
        <?php  echo '<select name="ITEM" id="user" class="textfield1">';
        while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
        echo '<option value="'.$res['productID'].'">';
        echo $res['SKU'] ; 
        echo'</option>';
        }
        echo'</select>';

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">             
    <div class="span3">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your page is refreshing? or you need to load it with ajax? jQuery maybe?

Comment: If i am right, you need the description value to be filled up with the corresponding description of the productID the user selects.

Comment: @Ravi yes that is what I aiming for

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

**First way** is by redirecting the page having a `$_GET` parameter which will contain the product id:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <label>SKU</label>
        <?php  echo '<select name="ITEM" id="user" class="textfield1" 
                      onchange="document.location=\'my-page.php?pid=\' + this.value">';
        while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
          echo '<option value="'.$res['productID'].'"';
          // LATER EDIT
            if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pid'] == $res['productID'])
              echo 'selected="selected"';
          // END LATER EDIT
          echo '>';
          echo $res['SKU'] ; 
          echo'</option>';
        }
        echo'</select>';

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">             
    <div class="span3">
        <label>Description</label>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['pid']) && is_numeric($_GET['pid'])) {
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT description 
                                    FROM products 
                                    WHERE product_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pid']) . "'");
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="description" value="<?=$row['description']?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second way** is to have an ajax call and fill description input dynamically, without refresing the page

```
// this is the JS code
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#user').change(function(){
       $.POST("my-ajax-call-page.php",
               {pid: $("#user").val()},
               function(data){
                   $('input[name="description"]').val(data.description);
               }, "json");
   });
});
```

and your `my-ajax-call-page.php` should be like this:

```
<?php
    include("mysql-connection.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT description 
                        FROM products 
                        WHERE product_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pid']) . "'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    echo json_encode("description" => $row['description']);
?>
```

You will find many examples and documentation for using jQuery library on [jQuery library website](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks very much @Matei Mihai. I opted for the refresh $_GET option as I understood it more. Sorry I am still learning so I'll look into AJAX later on. My only problem now is that after the page refreshes, the productID reverts to the first value in the option list but the product description is correct based on the selected productID before the refresh.

Comment: I've edited my answer, so search for LATER EDIT code. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <label>SKU</label>
        <?php  echo '<select name="ITEM" id="user" class="textfield1" onchange="showDesc()">';
        $desHTML = "";
        echo "<option value='0'>Please select</option>"
        while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
        echo '<option value="'.$res['productID'].'">';
        echo $res["SKU"] ; 
        echo'</option>';
        $desHTML .="<div class'descBox' id='".$res['productID']."' style='display:none'>".$res['description']."</div>";
        }
        echo'</select>';

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">             
    <div class="span3">
        <label>Description</label>
        <?php echo $desHTML; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now create one js function and call on onchange of select box.
Js function Hint:

$(".descBox").hide();
$("#"+selectedItemValue).show();

Let me know if you need any help for JS function.

Comment: You shouldnt insert `div` tags insert `select`. Also your div id is number, id (as name of any other variable) should start with character. To you this, at least generate your `div`s into php string, which you will print after your `select` and make their `id`s as `id="description'.$res['productID'].'"`

Comment: @sachin jat. Thanks very much for the reply. I am still learning so I opted for the onchange refresh code by Matei. I will definitely try your code though as soon as I figure out how to code the JS function. =)

Comment: function showDesc(){
$(".descBox").hide(); 
$("#"+$("#user").val()).show();
}

Please include jQuery lib files. :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us your SQL query, but I assume that you have a column named **description** and you are selecting this column in your query too.

So then, you can use jQuery to insert description of selected item to input

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3">
    <label>SKU</label>
    <?php  echo '<select name="ITEM" id="user" class="textfield1">';

    $js_array = array(); // This variable will contain your Javascript array with descriptions
    while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$res['productID'].'">';
    echo $res['SKU'] ; 
    echo'</option>';

    // Fill your array with descriptions; ID of item will be the index of array
    $js_array[$res['productID']] = $res['description'];
    }
    echo'</select>';
    ?>
    <script>
    var description;
    <?php
    foreach($js_array as $description => $id)
    {
      echo("description['".$id."'] = '".$description."';\n");
    }
    ?>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#user').change(function(){
        $("#description").val(description[$('#user').val()]);
      })
    });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">             
    <div class="span3">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Be sure to not forget to add `id` attribute to your `input type="text"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have opted to go with Matei's GET refresh code as I am still trying to learn (total noob) and it was the code I understood easiest. I will definitely experiment on your code though =)

Comment: No problem, this code may look little complex at first sight but its very easy too. This way you can update value of `input type=text` without refreshing the site and without extra php file. But if you have many items in the select (hundreds+) then Matei's **second way** will be best solution. Let me know in case of any questions